# base64 decode with one extra character

Tags: encoding, cryptography, base64, decoding

plain text: `abc123`
after base64 encoding: `YWJjMTIz`

When I decode `YWJjMTIz` with one extra character added in the end. Example: `YWJjMTIzE` it still decodes to original text: `abc123`

How does [base64 decoding](https://www.base64decode.org/) work and shouldn't I get a different result after adding extra character?

Answer (score 2):

As the name says, Base64 encodes binary data into a sequence of symbols drawn from an alphabet of 64, or put it differently: it encodes binary data as a base-64 number.

Each symbol encodes one of 64 values, or put another way, each symbol encodes 6 bits. So, if you add an additional symbol, you add 6 bits of data.

If we know that the original binary data was a sequence of 8-bit octets (for example, the input is UTF-8 encoded text), then we know that the 6 extra bits at the end are only a fragment and cannot possibly have come from the original binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Each base64 character is 6 bits.  A byte is 8 bits.  Hence, one byte is 2 base64 characters, two bytes are 3 base64 characters and three bytes are 4 base64 characters.  You can *never* have an odd single base64 character left at the end if you are encoding bytes.

Your base64 decoding software should throw an error or perhaps it is ignoring the extra character.